# Why doesn't cast work from NSData to String? Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have that code

```
func SendRequest(request: String) -> String
{
    var response = ""
    var (success, errmsg) = client.connect(timeout: 1)
    if success
    {
        var (success, errmsg) = client.send(str: request + "\n" )
        if success
        {
            while(true)
            {
                var data = client.read(10240*10)
                if (data == nil)
                {
                    break
                }
                var bytes = NSData.init(bytes: data!, length: data!.count)
                var str = String.init(data: bytes, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
                if str != nil{
                response += str!
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            print(errmsg)
        }
    }
    else
    {
        print(errmsg)
    }
    return response
}
```

Sometimes, cast `NSData` to `String` doesn't work. When I `print(str)` I see `nil`. Why is this happening? I use SwiftSocket library from GitHub. Sorry for my English.

This happening when my server send big `JSON` string. For example - if i received one object of message (my class) - everything always works. But if i received 4,5,6,... objects of message(my class) - this is working sometimes. MAGIC :( 
New version of code

```
func SendRequest(request: String) -> String
{
    var response = ""
    var bigData: [UInt8] = []
    var (success, errmsg) = client.connect(timeout: 1)
    if success
    {
        var (success, errmsg) = client.send(str: request + "\n" )
        if success
        {
            while(true)
            {
                var data = client.read(1024*10)
                if (data == nil)
                {
                    break

                }
                bigData.appendContentsOf(data!)
            }
        }
        else
        {
            print(errmsg)
        }
    }
    else
    {
        print(errmsg)
    }
    var bytes = NSData.init(bytes: bigData, length: bigData.count)

    if let str = String(data: bytes, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) as String? {
        print(str)
        response = str
    }
    return response
}
```

Comment: sometimes the data may be more complex than a String and may need to be casted to an NSArray or NSDictionary try adding this

Comment: i received only JSON strings from my server - that is "more complex than a String" ??

Comment: Check that `bytes` are not `nil`.

Comment: @AlexanderDoloz `bytes` are full. not `nil`

Comment: Could it be because your data is not complete? What if instead of appending string, you append the NSData (NSMutableData), and at the end, you convert it to `NSString` if the portion return nil for NSString conversion. Let's imagine that a character is written "1001" (as data), but  you receive only "10", and the next time you receive the "01". To transform it you need to get the whole data.

Comment: @Larme, I think you might be on to something, there. If a multi-byte character is split between two batches of data, it might not be a valid UTF-8 string...

Comment: @MarkBessey: Without speaking Swift, I'd go like this: `var historicData = NSMutableData.init()` before the loop, and replace the if test for validity with: `if str != nil{ historicData.length = 0 //remove the bytes since it's valid response += str! } else { historicData.appendData(bytes) }`, or something similar. Else, a good info would be to log each time `bytes`, and see what's in there (if there is no sensitive data, obviously), see how much times it's called, etc when a message is send.

Comment: @Larme you are right! Thank you! I am a beginner in "Network Data Sending". Can you look at my update of topic? It is right way?

Comment: It seems correct. If it works, great!

Comment: yes, it is work! thank you once again!!

Comment: @AndreyMorozov I posted the answer. If it's suited to your question, please mark it as such, in order to help future developer with the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: I don't speak Swift. This following code may not compile, but it should give you the main idea/logic behind it.

The issue was because there `NSData` was incomplete (you receive them piece by piece and the buffer size may not be sufficient to handle the complete response at once), assuming that the bytes are really transformable to `NSString` according to the encoding used, as [@zaph](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36897806/1801544) pointed out. 
Simple example: Transform a `UIImage` into `NSData` using `UIImageJPEGRepresentation()` for example, and try to transform it into `NSString` using the wanted encoding, it may not be valid, or do the same with the stream of a video.

An example for our case:
Full valid "Character": "1001", nothing with "10" nor "01".
You receive "10" only. And if you convert it to `NSString`, it's nil because it's not valid.
Then, you receive "01". And if you convert it to `NSString`, it's nil because it's not valid.
So you have to read all the `NSData` before transforming it to `NSString`.

So at the beginning, you can create a `var finalData = NSMutableData.init()`
Then, each time you read the buffer, do:

```
var partialData = NSData.init(bytes: data, length: data.count)
finalData.appendData(partialData)
```

At the end, just transform `finalData` to `String`:

```
if let str = String(data:finalData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
    response = str
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Some possibilities to examine include whether or not data actually contains any bytes, and whether or not it's actually a valid UTF-8 string. Assuming this is an http request/response that you're handling, check the `Content-type`, in particular the `charset` property. If the data's encoded as something other than text , or it's not UTF-8 format, it won't convert to a string.

Answer (score 1):

Answering: "Sometimes, cast NSData to String doesn't work."
Not all data is convertible to a particular string encoding. In the case:

```
var str = String.init(data: bytes, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
```

there are a great number of bytes and byte sequences that have no valid UTF-8 character encoding.