# NSLog show strange character instead of the JSON

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nslog, nsstream, nsmutablestring

I have this code below that handles the response send by my server with sockets:

```
uint8_t buffer[4096];
        int len;
        NSMutableString *total = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        while ([inputStream hasBytesAvailable]) {
            len = (int)[inputStream read:buffer maxLength:sizeof(buffer)];
            if (len > 0) {

                NSLog(@"Buffer: %s",buffer);
                [total appendString: [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:buffer length:len encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
                NSLog(@"Receive: %@, len: %d",total,len);
                NSLog(@"len: %d, receive: %@",len,total);

}

}
```

My server send a text file like this:

```
[{"name_user":"stack overflow","user_key":"XXXXXXX","type":21}]
```

The problem with this code is, if I send that JSON, the console log shows the length of that JSON. But If I send this JSON below:

```
[[{"name_user":"stack overflow","user_key":"XXXXXXX","type":21}],[{"name_user":"lacrifilm","user_key":"XXXXXXX","type":21}]]
```

That represents two values in JSON the console log shows:

```
Buffer: ~
Receive: ~
len: 184, receive: ~
```

I believe the problem is not in my server, because if it was I would be getting: `Receive: ~, len: 184`, instead of `Receive: ~` without `len: 184` as we saw in the second call of `NSLog` in my command above.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why doesn't cast work from NSData to String? Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36894972/why-doesnt-cast-work-from-nsdata-to-string-swift)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are building up your string incorrectly. You are reading a series of bytes, not pieces of a string. So build up an `NSMutableData`, and then create an `NSString` once you have all of the data. More like this:

```
uint8_t buffer[4096];
NSMutableData *data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
while ([inputStream hasBytesAvailable]) {
    NSInteger len = [inputStream read:buffer maxLength:sizeof(buffer)];
    if (len > 0) {
        //NSLog(@"Buffer: %s",buffer); // can't do this - buffer isn't a null-terminated C-string
        [data appendBytes:buffer length:len];
        NSLog(@"Receive: %@, len: %d", data, (int)len);
    }
}

NSString *total = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"Total: %@", total);
```

Comment: It works, I can see the hash of NSData but the NSString total is returning `null`, I believe that when I convert it to an NSArray I can see the values right?

Comment: If `total` is `nil` but `data` seems to have the right amount of data, then the string may not be in UTF-8 encoding. Do you know what string encoding your server is using?

Comment: And if you actually are using NSJSONSerialization, then there is no need to create a string. Just pass `data` in directly. Though that only works if `NSData` is a string encoded in one of 5 specific encodings (see the docs).